# Home page is getting current-menu-item even if it's not home

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, customization

After upgrading to 3.1 I am seeing this issue.

I use custom post types and when you click on the menu items either Games, Entertainment or Tech it gets the class current-menu-item but home link still has it also.

I am using the custom menu's built into WordPress and for the links and they are just custom links pointing to:

- Home: http://www.flesheatingzipper.com
- Games: http://www.flesheatingzipper.com/games/
- Entertainment: http://www.flesheatingzipper.com/entertainment/
- Tech: http://www.flesheatingzipper.com/tech/
- About: Links to page, about

Here is the site: http://www.flesheatingzipper.com/

Comment: You'll need to share a bit more details, like how your menu is set up etc. .

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: Can't replicate this on my install, home link only gets current on the home page, how are you adding the home link to the menu? (custom link?) Same question for problem links, are they custom or pages, or something else?

Comment: The home, games, entertainment and tech are custom links. About and contact are page links. When you click on one of the page links the home link does not get the class. It only has the class when you click on the games, entertainment or tech links. Those links are of course pulling type-[games/entertainment/tech].php. Like I was saying it was working fine in 3.0 and just started happening after upgrading to 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the checkboxes / add Pages / add Categories rather than custom links when adding items to the menu? It's sorta the opposite problem, but I've run into issues where WP does not recognize custom links as "this page" - maybe the fix is the same.

** EDIT **

I just ran across this thread in the WP forums which might help with your issue. Read comments from this point on down for a few suggested workarounds.  http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-parent#post-1775314

Comment: They are custom post types so they don't show up as an option check off.

Comment: Thanks for searching. I just ended up using JS to remove the class.